# plai-typed : how to define function type?

Tags: functional-programming, racket, static-typing, plai

I'm playing with plai-type language. I have a function which should consume a predicate function (returning true or false) and a list of items.

My code looks like:

```
(define-type-alias IndexT (listof IndexItemT))

(define (index->filter pf [index : IndexT]) : IndexT
  (filter pf index))
```

and I'd like to express that `pf` can consume value of type `IndexItemT` and return `bool`.

Is it possible to write it in plai-typed lang? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`->`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plai-typed/Types.html?q=plai%20typed#%28form._%28%28lib._plai-typed%2Fmain..rkt%29._-~3e%29%29) type constructor to express the type of `pf`.

```
(define (index->filter [pf : (IndexItemT -> boolean)] [index : IndexT]) : IndexT
  ....)
```